# FatalErrorException : syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This thing is bugging me a lot. I'm getting this parse error:  `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pratice/storage/framework/views/36f62563d0e17e05a5f15bec012dd0cd at line 21`

My view file is

```
@extends('layouts.loginlayout')

@section('content')

    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {!! session('status') !!}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif 
//this is line 21
    {!! Form:open() !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('email','Email:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'email']) !!}
        </div>

        {!! Form::submit('Login',['class'=>'btn pull-right default-button']) !!}


    {!! Form:close() !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: And which line is line 21?

Comment: between @endif and {!! Form:open() !!}

Comment: `Form:open()` instead of `Form::open ()`?

Comment: not solve ..got same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change  `{!! Form:open() !!}` to

```
  {!! Form::open() !!}
```

and  `{!! Form:close() !!}` to

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```